# How can I re-activate an existing question to expand on it?

Tags: support, comments, bump, last-activity, question-activity

I've just come across this question on SO: [Implementation of achievement systems in modern, complex games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343538/implementation-of-achievement-systems-in-modern-complex-games)

I want to expand on it with an "extra" question, and so I've added a comment. However, the question does not reactivate itself (stays on "active 5 months ago") because of my comment. Earlier today, I could not get a question to get reactivated by commenting on an answer.

I believe this used to be different, with any activity except votes reactivating the question. My alternatives seem to be to offer a bounty but that's overkill, or make an edit which isn't necessary at all.

What can I do? And why don't comments re-activate a question?

Comment: Bounties are the only (valid) option, if you want to bump it on the active page.

Comment: @fbueckert in that case, I'm risking rep to get nothing in return. The focus of attention won't be my comment requesting a different answer.

Comment: You can put a custom message into your bounty.  Then within that week, you can award it to any answer on that question.  The only risk is if no one answers it in the manner you want, and one of the new answers gets a couple upvotes.  Then they get half the bounty.

Comment: I still think that comments are a valid thing to re-activate a question...

Comment: Why should they be?  If they did, the active page would be refreshed several hundred times a **day**.  Probably more than that every hour on SO.

Comment: Comments are for requesting clarification on the post. They are not meant for asking your own questions or expanding the question, and therefore there is absolutely no reason why a comment should ever bump a post.

Comment: You both have a valid point.

Comment: Yeesh, dat bounty.  If it was a standalone question it'd be off topic.  Way broad, way speculation, no programming.  Might be a better topic for another SE network site which I won't mention because I haven't checked what's on topic there...

Comment: @Won't I know on Arqade that would be off-topic.  GameDev, I have no idea.

Comment: As I said in my answer, might have a chance in Programmers. It's conceptional after all.

Comment: @fbueckert: Not Arquade, but there might be a site that deals with, I dunno, games, and like, uh, development, or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should open your own question.

The question you mention is only loosely related to your question, in fact it specifically asks about the implementation of achievements in *modern* games, while your questions asks about "older games that weren't designed with achievements in mind".

You have a separate question, you should not post it as a comment and also not try to hijack the original question by opening a bounty for your question on it.

As you said yourself in the comments above:

> in that case, I'm risking rep to get nothing in return. The focus of attention won't be my comment requesting a different answer

That should be warning sign enough for you that the existing question will not solve your problem.

Open a new question and put in a link to the other question as a reference.

PS: I am not sure your question belongs on SO at all. You don't seem to have a programming problem you want to solve, instead you are interested in how this is done by Steam and similar platforms. This would probably belong either on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or [gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).